# jquery: how to get value from htmlstring?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

i have a script like this:

```
<script>
    var stuff = '<input id="testinput" name="testinput" type="text" value="this is the right one" /><input id="testinput2" name="testinput2" type="text" value="this is the wrong one" />'
</script>
```

How can I with jQuery get the value ("this is the wrong one") from the stuff variable?

Answer (score 7):

Use `.val` method.

```
var value = $(stuff).val();
```

***Update:***
Did not notice there is multiple input in your string.
In the case, you need to use `.map` method to return the values as an array.

***[The demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/AjCh7/)***

```
var stuff = '<input id="testinput" name="testinput" type="text" value="this is the one" /><input id="testinput2" name="testinput2" type="text" value="this is the wrong one" />';

console.log($(stuff).map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
}));​
```

Comment: The Boss way haha one liner helped a lot it is actually kind of returning an element

Answer (score 6):

```
var stuff = '<input id="testinput" name="testinput" type="text" value="this is the one" /><input id="testinput2" name="testinput2" type="text" value="this is the wrong one" />';

console.log($(stuff).val()); // This is the one
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/Bfmxd/)

```
console.log($($(stuff)[1]).val());​ // This is the wrong one
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `val()` for getting the value or if you are after an attribute use `.attr()`

```
var v = $(stuff).val();

var attr = $(stuff).attr('attribute you want');
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with selectors failing, until I did this:

```js
var stuff = '<input id="testinput" name="testinput" type="text" value="this is the one" /><input id="testinput2" name="testinput2" type="text" value="this is the wrong one" />';

var myValue = HtmlElementAttribute(stuff, 'testinput2', 'value');

function HtmlElementAttribute(htmlString, elementId, attributeName) {
    var foundValue = '';
    $(htmlString).filter(function (x) {
        var idX = eval('$(htmlString)[x].id');
        if (idX && idX == elementId) {
            foundValue = $(eval('$(htmlString)[x].outerHTML')).attr(attributeName);
        }
    });
    return foundValue;
}
```